# Unable to perform automatically routes file upgrade (rails-upgrade)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I've got Rails2 application and I'm trying to upgrade it to Rails3 (plugin: https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade).

Everything was fine till step of routes file upgrade. When I've tried to use `rake rails:upgrade:routes` following error displayed:

```
    /home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
    (in /home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo)
    WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.11) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
    WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x
    DEPRECATION WARNING: config.action_controller.session= has been deprecated. Please use config.session_store(name, options) instead. (called from <class:Application> at /home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/config/application.rb:54)
    DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in /home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/vendor/plugins/event_calendar/tasks/event_calendar_tasks.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from <top (required)> at /home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/Rakefile:7)
    rake aborted!
    undefined method `now' for nil:NilClass

    (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Current Rails ver: 2.3.9
Destination ver: 3.0.3

What is worng? May I missed something? Maybe it's rake fault, but I'm not sure.

Edit: rake rails:upgrade:routes --trace

```
chmarus@Arti:~/Pulpit/mmo$ rake rails:upgrade:routes --trace
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/alt_system.rb:32: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
(in /home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo)
WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.11) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x
DEPRECATION WARNING: config.action_controller.session= has been deprecated. Please use config.session_store(name, options) instead. (called from <class:Application> at /home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/config/application.rb:54)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in /home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/vendor/plugins/event_calendar/tasks/event_calendar_tasks.rake are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from <top (required)> at /home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/Rakefile:7)
** Invoke rails:upgrade:routes (first_time)
** Execute rails:upgrade:routes
rake aborted!
undefined method `now' for nil:NilClass
/home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/vendor/plugins/rails_upgrade/lib/routes_upgrader.rb:47:in `module_eval'
/home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/vendor/plugins/rails_upgrade/lib/routes_upgrader.rb:18:in `draw'
(eval):1:in `upgrade_routes'
/home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/vendor/plugins/rails_upgrade/lib/routes_upgrader.rb:47:in `module_eval'
/home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/vendor/plugins/rails_upgrade/lib/routes_upgrader.rb:47:in `upgrade_routes'
/home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/vendor/plugins/rails_upgrade/lib/routes_upgrader.rb:28:in `generate_new_routes'
/home/chmarus/Pulpit/mmo/vendor/plugins/rails_upgrade/lib/tasks/rails_upgrade_tasks.rake:29:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `block in execute'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/rubies/ruby-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `block in top_level'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `block in run'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/home/chmarus/.rvm/gems/ruby-head@rails3/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you run it with --trace so we can see the backtrace where the error is occurring?

Comment: Please look at updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is occurring when it parses your routes.rb file. Look out for the `now` keyword in config/routes.rb. See https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade/blob/master/lib/routes_upgrader.rb#L38 line 47.

If you don't see the call to `now` or don't know how to fix it from there, edit the question and post your routes.rb file, leave a comment, and we can take a closer look.

Comment: Thanks for answer. My old routes.rb file has one route from calendar plugin which is causing this crash. I deleted it and now upgrade script is working properly.